# Synchronization Fraud Protection

Tags: synchronization

Suppose I want to synchronize my chain. I download the blocks and state from a Node. What if this node is malicious? It can give me an alternative chain that I won't be able to distinguish from the real one. Some blocks of this alternative chain will be already finalized so I won't be able to rollback if I receive the real chain in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter for you whether it can be rolled back or not. If you are part of a "wrong chain" and use your assets there, it means the assets are still in your account in the "right" chain. The only bad thing would be if you somehow manage to use assets in the "right" chain to get assets in the "wrong" chain, but I don't see how that would be possible easily.

Furthermore, you should always be connected to multiple nodes. It's not an explicit settings, it's just how nodes operate - they gossip about other nodes and, with some logic, your node connects with those other nodes.

Comment: Yes, from my point of view I'm in the "right" chain. But really I am not. You say that I should be connected to several nodes. So if I have no chain and want to sync, then I should ask all nodes who I am connected to and choose the most difficult chain among those that they have proposed?

Comment: Your node client should take care of that all. It should have logic to decide which chain to follow.